# How to calculate Puiseux series for $x^{e^x}$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series, laurent-series, formal-power-series

Mathematica gives the result:

$$x+x^2\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2}x^3(\ln(x)+\ln(x)^2)+\frac{1}{6}x^4(\ln(x)+3\ln(x)^2+\ln(x)^3)+...$$

I have searched for solved examples or step-by-step tutorials calculating Puiseux expansions of functions, but didn't find good sources.

I want to know the formula or the algorithm to obtain such terms up to degree $n$.

Comment: I’d bet rewriting it as $\exp(e^x\log x)$ then expanding the exponentials will get you what you want.

Comment: @Aruralreader That alone would not expand the function as a Puiseux series with terms in both $x^i$ and $\ln x$.

Comment: Works for me. I get $x^{e^x} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\, a_k(\log x)x^k$ where
\begin{align}
a_1(L) &= 1 \\
a_2(L) &= L \\
a_3(L) &= \tfrac{1}{2}L + \tfrac{1}{2}L^2 \\
a_4(L) &= \tfrac{1}{6}L + \tfrac{1}{2}L^2 + \tfrac{1}{6}L^3 \\
a_5(L) &= \tfrac{1}{24}L + \tfrac{7}{24}L^2 + \tfrac{1}{4}L^3 + \tfrac{1}{24}L^4 \\
a_6(L) &= \tfrac{1}{120}L + \tfrac{1}{8}L^2 + \tfrac{5}{24}L^3 + \tfrac{1}{12}L^4 + \tfrac{1}{120}L^5,
\end{align}
etc.

Comment: I don’t see much by way of OP motivation or effort. Maybe a candidate for closing?

Comment: It's funny because I don't see any useful comment from you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the exponential generating function of the [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials) to obtain
$$
x^{{\rm e}^x }  = {\rm e}^{{\rm e}^x \log x}  = x{\rm e}^{({\rm e}^x  - 1)\log x}  = x\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{T_n (\log x)}{n!}x^n 
$$
for $x>0$.

Comment: Very nice @Gary, I hadn’t heard of the Touchard polynomials. I worked through the series expansion in $x$ of $e^{e^x L}$. Then replacing the $e^L$ terms with $x$ and rearranging…

Comment: @Gary thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for